# Error on ionic deep linking , on ionic 3 / Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, ionic3

Error on ionic deeplinking ,

**Error:** Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Deeplinks.route (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:94242:126)

**Code:**

```
constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private deeplinks: Deeplinks) {


platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();



  this.deeplinks.route({
      '/': {},
      '/reset-password/:Id': MmresetpasswordPage
    })
    .subscribe(match => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(match));
    }, nomatch => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(nomatch));

    });

});
```

Comment: you need to set public/private to your object in constructor.

Comment: CodeChanger: give me an example?

Comment: Same error I am facing in version ionic 3 and angular 5. Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 1):

Install the v5 of deeplinks: `npm i -s @ionic-native/deeplinks@5`

Import in `component`s and `module`s like: `import {Deeplinks} from '@ionic-native/deeplinks/ngx'` (note `/ngx` at end)

Then declare in `component.ts` like: `constructor(private deeplinks:Deeplinks){}`

Then Provide in `app.module.ts` like: `providers:[Deeplinks]`

Comment: I have the same configuration but still getting the error with the code that you have mentioned above : 
Following is the error I am getting :
core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.